# How to return count of unique IDs from table 1 based on shared order ID from table 2 and limiting by Date parameter

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to set up a query for use in a report. My sql-server database has one table (`dbo.assignment`) that lists a row for every unique work assignment in the system. The second table is a temporary table (`#OpenOrder`) constructed from a separate table (`dbo.orderschedule`) which contains all the order IDs. The report is supposed to show a row for every order ID, and then have a column that shows a count of every assignment ID entered on a specific date that shares the same order ID.

[dbo.assignment] Columns:

```
 [StaffingOrderGUID],[AssignmentID],[DateEntered]
```

[dbo.orderschedule] Columns:

```
[StaffingOrderGUID],[StaffingOrderID]
```

I've tried using INNER JOIN to return a match on staffingorderguid (the only value shared between the two tables) and when I exclude the date condition, I get a count of 66 assignment IDs for every order, which is definitely not correct as most orders only have 1-3 assignments tied to them. If I use LEFT JOIN I get the total number of assignments in the whole system, but the problem is that it is giving me this count for every order and is not showing the assignment IDs that just tie to the individual order.

When I add in the WHERE statement to tie the `DateEntered` to the date chosen on my `@StartDate` parameter, then I get zero results for any order regardless if I am using INNER or LEFT JOIN.

```
UPDATE #OpenOrder
SET SupervisorName = (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT ag.AssignmentGUID)
FROM dbo.Assignment AS ag
     INNER JOIN #OpenOrder oe ON ag.StaffingOrderGUID = oe.StaffingOrderGUID
WHERE ag.DateEntered = @StartDate)
```

I expected this code to return something like this in the actual report:

```
Order ID: 1111 | Assignments: 3 
Order ID: 1112 | Assignments: 2
Order ID: 1113 | Assignments: 0
```

What I get instead is this. When I use `INNER JOIN`:

```
Order ID: 1111 | Assignments: 66
Order ID: 1112 | Assignments: 66
Order ID: 1113 | Assignments: 66
```

When I use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Order ID: 1111 | Assignments: 200092
Order ID: 1112 | Assignments: 200092
Order ID: 1113 | Assignments: 200092
```

When I add the `WHERE` statement to limit by date:

```
Order ID: 1111 | Assignments: 0
Order ID: 1112 | Assignments: 0
Order ID: 1113 | Assignments: 0
```

Clearly the code is not successfully tying the count of assignments to the order that they are associated with, but I can't figure out where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to join on a derived table with your aggregate. The reason you are getting the same value in your sub-query for all rows is because [it isn't correlated](https://www.quora.com/SQL-What-is-the-difference-between-a-correlated-and-an-uncorrelated-subquery) to the outer query, which is the `UPDATE`. Note, the `JOIN` to the same table you are updating in the sub-query doesn't correlate it to the rows in the `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE O
SET O.SupervisorName = ag.CT
FROM  #OpenOrder O
INNER JOIN
    (select  
        count(distinct AssignmentGUID) as CT
        ,StaffingOrderGUID 
    from  dbo.Assignment 
    group by StaffingOrderGUID) ag on ag.StaffingOrderGUID = O.StaffingOrderGUI
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This was exactly the problem and changing the table being updated caused the numbers to correlate to the orders like I wanted them to. I also found that I was formatting my Date request incorrectly. Once I changed it to be like the following:

`WHERE cast(DateEntered as date) = @StartDate`

then it all started working as expected. I very much appreciate the help!

Comment: You bet @MattJA good luck! I used the derived table here as it's the most common approach without a window function.